# write variable in netcdf file

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I define a variable like: 
`VAR(t,o)` with Dimensions: t=4 and o=11

IERREU = nf90_def_var(ncid, "var", nf90_real, (/ oID, tID /), VarID)

That looks like:

```
VAR(1,1)=5
VAR(2,1)=2
VAR(3,1)=8
VAR(4,1)=9
VAR(1,2)=5
VAR(2,2)=2
VAR(3,2)=8
VAR(4,2)=9
....
VAR(1,11)=5
VAR(2,11)=2
VAR(3,11)=8
VAR(4,11)=9
```

To write the variable in the netcdf file, I do:

```
IERREU = nf90_put_var(ncid, VarID, VAR)
```

In the netcdf, I want to have the data of my variable order like:

```
VAR=5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
    9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9;
```

And I get this:

```
VAR= 5,2,8,9,5,2,8,9,5,2,8,
     9,5,2,8,9,5,2,8,9,5,2,
     8,9,5,2,8,9,5,2,8,9,5,
     2,8,9,5,2,8,9,5,2,8,9;
```

How can I define the order of the data ?

Comment: What is the relation between `lat` and `VAR`? please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, it is an error...

Comment: Can you add the line of code that defines your netcdf variable (varID)? What (software) are you using to to visualize your data in the netcdf?

Comment: I have added the line. I use ncview ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep the dimension order of your array the same in your program yet transpose it in the netCDF file then you have two options.

Just write the transpose

`IERREU = nf90_put_var(ncid, VarID, transpose(VAR))`

or use the `map` vector argument

`IERREU = nf90_put_var(ncid, VarID, VAR, map=(/ t,1 /))`

This case is covered in the standard netCDF documentation for `nf90_put_var`

[  [1](http://%20%20[1]:%20http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR.html#NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR[1]]): http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR.html#NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR[1](http://%20%20[1]:%20http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-f90/NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR.html#NF90_005fPUT_005fVAR[1]])]

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions must be in the same order for the definition of the variable in the netcdf and in the declaration of the variable that you are saving.

The definition of the variable in the netcdf is right for what you want to achieve. So you should have `VAR(o,t)`, and the order of indexes must change in the initialization of `VAR`. Since you want have the exact same value in each row of your matrix as seen by ncview, I advise you to initialize the fortran matrix as

```
var(:,1) = 5
var(:,2) = 2
var(:,3) = 8
var(:,4) = 9
```

This way, you are sure that everything is done right. Keep in mind that order of dimensions in fortran is not the same in ncview.

I assumed that `(/ o, t /)` in `IERREU = nf90_def_var(ncid, "var", nf90_real, (/ o, t /), VarID)` is only a typo, and that you actually have something like `IERREU = nf90_def_var(ncid, "var", nf90_real, (/ oid, tid /), VarID)` where `oid` and `tid` are result from a call to `nf90_def_dim`. You should edit your post if that is the case.

Comment: You are right, it is /oid, tid/ in my code. I have use the same values in my matrix VAR but it was only to illustrate my problem and simplify things.